# What is the correct way to compare times in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

The following example is confusing me. Why does the comparison return false?

```
require 'active_support/time'

time1 = Time.new.utc.end_of_day  # 2013-01-09 23:59:59 UTC
time2 = Time.parse(time1.to_s)   # 2013-01-09 23:59:59 UTC

time1 == time2                   # false
time1.eql?(time2)                # false 
time1.equal?(time2)              # false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the parsed version doesn't include microseconds?

Comment: Do you microseconds? I'm totally confused by this

Comment: Why would `end_of_day` set them to 0? It's counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: yes, I meant microseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time2` is generated from a string representation of `time1` which lacks information. Namely, the microseconds.

```
require 'active_support/time'

time1 = Time.new.utc.end_of_day  # => 2013-01-09 23:59:59 UTC
time2 = Time.parse(time1.to_s)   # => 2013-01-09 23:59:59 UTC

time1.usec # => 999999
time2.usec # => 0
```

### Workaround:

If you don't need microsecond precision, you can round both timestamps to seconds.

```
time1.to_i == time2.to_i # => true
```

Comment: Why what? Why microseconds aren't included in `Time#to_s`?

Comment: What do you mean, "half cooked"? It correctly parsed the string and used the information you provided. And it did not use information you didn't provide.

Comment: Hmm. I get it now. But I don't know how to solve my original problem. Which stemmed from using Mongoid's Time field.

Comment: Well I'm happy that you're here :)